# How to bind IIS://localhost/MimeMap to something other than the default website

Tags: iis-7, mime-types

I need to get the MIME types for the "current" website my code is running under, not the list of global MIME types assigned to IIS in general.  I have some MIME types locally assigned to just a specific website, types I only want on this site and not server wide across all websites.

DirectoryEntry Path = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/MimeMap");

using this above I get just those global IIS MIME types.  I've tried:

DirectoryEntry Path = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host + "/MimeMap");

with no success.  I get the same list of global MIME types, and not the local ones I've assigned to the site running the code.

I was originally using a method that required me to reference Microsoft.Web.Administration from the WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv directory, but I'd rather not reference that if I don't have to.

Thanks.